# How to print/list only 5 entries from OS.Walk?

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop, count, os.walk

#### The problem

I posted this question a bit ago (Here: [print/list only 5 entries from OS.Walk in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65660384/print-list-only-5-entries-from-os-walk-in-python)) and it worked then. Now, out of nowhere, **it stopped only showing only 5 results and started showing me everything again.**

#### The Goal:

To list only 5 entries when using OS walk. So far I have only been able to get a list of everything that I find using OS.Walk or only list one entry.
I was using:

```
for file in files[0:5]: #You show the first five only
```

to get the first five results and not it's giving me all the results again.

Here is the full code:

```
import os
import subprocess


def playmusic(name):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk('E:\\', followlinks=True):
        for file in files[0:5]: #You show the first five only
            if name in file:
                vlc='C:/Program Files/VideoLAN/VLC/vlc.exe'
                music=str(os.path.join(root,file))
                print(music)
                #subprocess.Popen([vlc, music])
                #return
    print("Finish")
    input()
try:
    s=raw_input("name: ")
    playmusic(s)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    print("Error")
```

Here is the result

```
name: te
E:\PC Games\Assassin's Creed\Detection\Detection.exe
E:\PC Games\Assassin's Creed\Detection\detectionapi_rd.dll
E:\PC Games\Assassin's Creed\Detection\directx10tests_rd.dll
E:\PC Games\Assassin's Creed\Detection\directx9tests_rd.dll
E:\PC Games\Assassin's Creed\Detection\directxtests_rd.tst
E:\PC Games\Assassin's Creed\Detection\localization\CZ\interpreter_local.ini
E:\PC Games\Assassin's Creed\Detection\localization\DEU\interpreter_local.ini
E:\PC Games\Assassin's Creed\Detection\localization\EN\interpreter_local.ini
E:\PC Games\Assassin's Creed\Detection\localization\ESM\interpreter_local.ini

more results than what is show here...
```

I tried doing a couple of different things.

Like using a counter:

```
import os
import subprocess


def playmusic(name):
    count = 0
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk('E:\\', followlinks=True):
        for file in files:
            if name in file:
                vlc='C:/Program Files/VideoLAN/VLC/vlc.exe'
                music=str(os.path.join(root,file))
                print(music)
                count = count + 1 
                if count == 5:
                    break
                #subprocess.Popen([vlc, music])
                #return
    print("Finish")
    input()
try:
    s=raw_input("name: ")
    playmusic(s)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    print("Error")
```

Result:

```
name: te
E:\PC Games\Assassin's Creed\Detection\Detection.exe
E:\PC Games\Assassin's Creed\Detection\detectionapi_rd.dll
E:\PC Games\Assassin's Creed\Detection\directx10tests_rd.dll
E:\PC Games\Assassin's Creed\Detection\directx9tests_rd.dll
E:\PC Games\Assassin's Creed\Detection\directxtests_rd.tst
E:\PC Games\Assassin's Creed\Detection\localization\CZ\interpreter_local.ini
E:\PC Games\Assassin's Creed\Detection\localization\DEU\interpreter_local.ini
E:\PC Games\Assassin's Creed\Detection\localization\EN\interpreter_local.ini
E:\PC Games\Assassin's Creed\Detection\localization\ESM\interpreter_local.ini

more results than what is shown here...
```

Or trying `range`:

```
import os
import subprocess


def playmusic(name):
    for i in range(5):
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk('E:\\', followlinks=True):
            for file in files:
                if name in file:
                    vlc='C:/Program Files/VideoLAN/VLC/vlc.exe'
                    music=str(os.path.join(root,file))
                    print(music)
                    i += 1
                    if i == 5:
                        break
                    #subprocess.Popen([vlc, music])
                    #return
    print("Finish")
    input()
try:
    s=raw_input("name: ")
    playmusic(s)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    print("Error")
```

Result:

```
name: te
E:\PC Games\Assassin's Creed\Detection\Detection.exe
E:\PC Games\Assassin's Creed\Detection\detectionapi_rd.dll
E:\PC Games\Assassin's Creed\Detection\directx10tests_rd.dll
E:\PC Games\Assassin's Creed\Detection\directx9tests_rd.dll
E:\PC Games\Assassin's Creed\Detection\directxtests_rd.tst
E:\PC Games\Assassin's Creed\Detection\localization\CZ\interpreter_local.ini
E:\PC Games\Assassin's Creed\Detection\localization\DEU\interpreter_local.ini
E:\PC Games\Assassin's Creed\Detection\localization\EN\interpreter_local.ini
E:\PC Games\Assassin's Creed\Detection\localization\ESM\interpreter_local.ini

more results than what is show here...
```

Still, I get more results than five.

Is there any reason why the code would stop working? Like indentation or something? Or did I miss something? I have been looking into this all weekend and with no results so far.

Also if someone has any other ideas or methods that would be awesome.

#### Research

https://www.w3resource.com/python/python-break-continue.php 
[End loop with counter and condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44481346/end-loop-with-counter-and-condition)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is doing exactly what you asked.  It is showing you 5 files from each directory, and then moves into each subdirectory, where it shows you 5 from each.  If you want it to stop everything after handling 5 lines, you need to exit both loops.

```
import os
import subprocess

def playmusic(name):
    count = 0
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk('E:\\', followlinks=True):
        for file in files:
            if name in file:
                vlc='C:/Program Files/VideoLAN/VLC/vlc.exe'
                music=str(os.path.join(root,file))
                print(music)
                count = count + 1 
                if count == 5:
                    break
        if count >= 5:
            break
    print("Finish")
```

Comment: OMG this worked! I thought I something like that in another stackoverflow question where the person didn't break both loops. I tried putting another break but I didn't put a if count >=  5: for the second break. This makes a lot of sense in that fact that I have to break both loops.